# Tags angular-components and angular-components is too different tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

- **angularjs-components** - are just components that could be used with angularJs
- **angularjs-component** - is new concept of Angular 1.5 (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

So we need either to keep both or to remove first one (because second one is more semantically correct)

the link to edit - https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/115692

Comment: Having difficulty finding the tags you are talking about.  Do you mean [tag:angularjs-components]?  And I don't see a tag for [tag:angularjs-component] or [tag:angular-component] or anything else similar..

Comment: thx, updated to angularjs-components

Comment: Your question is still too confusing because you are rely on the edit link to illustrate the issue.  The edit is not visible top anyone without  enough rep in that tag.  Can I assume someone is trying to edit the wiki for [tag:angularjs-components] to include a description of angularjs-component as well?